# How can the title attribute of an img element by accessed from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, image

There is empty div that an image element will be inserted.

```
<div id="divOne" class="div"></div> 
<!-- blank div this is the html div, and is blank so as to append img using js code below. -->
```

I am then using JavaSctipt to add the image to the DOM.

```
var createImage = function(src, title) {
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = src;
 img.title = title;
 return img;
};

var imgArray = [];
imgArray.push(createImage('Assets/banana.png', 'banana'));

divOne.append(imgArray[0]);
```

How can the tittle attribute of the image be accessed? for example

```
divOne.onclick = function divOneClicked() {

 console.log('div 1 clicked');

 if ( ???.title == winImg.title) {
 console.log('banana/lose');
 }
}
```

how do i compare the titles of the div img with another img's title?

Comment: Where/When do you want to access the title? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Are you asking about the title in the array, or the title of the image element within the DOM structure?

Comment: so, i have the array of images and i have appended imgArray[0] on divOne. With 'on click' function of divOne i want to compare the img title in the divOne with the img title another image which is not in the array.

Comment: `function divOneClicked(e) { var title = e.target.children[0].title; ...`

Answer (score 0):

You're loading them into an array, take a look at this option:

```js
var createImage = function(src, title) {
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = src;
 img.title = title;
 return img;
};

var imgArray = [];
imgArray.push(createImage('Assets/banana.png', 'banana'));
imgArray.push(createImage('Assets/orange.png', 'orange'));
imgArray.push(createImage('Assets/grapefruit.png', 'grapefruit'));

// Here I access a property of one of the elements...
 console.log(imgArray[0].title);
```

If, instead, you're looking for the title of an image element in the DOM itself, try:

```js
var createImage = function(src, title) {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
  img.title = title;
  return img;
};

var imgArray = [];
imgArray.push(createImage('Assets/banana.png', 'banana'));
imgArray.push(createImage('Assets/orange.png', 'orange'));
imgArray.push(createImage('Assets/grapefruit.png', 'grapefruit'));

for (var i = 0, j = imgArray.length; i < j; i++) {
  var el = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.appendChild(imgArray[i]);
  el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    var myImage = this.querySelector("img");
    console.log(myImage.title);
  });
}
```

Edited this one to iterate over the imgArray and create divs for each image. Each div will display its own child image's title, by handling its own click.

Comment: Thnx for this, but how do i get the title of img when clicking the div?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you. Check it out, @mpouzouxis

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

imgArray[i].title  for any index i

Comment: I think your on the right track, an example would make your answer more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `$('img', "#divOne").attr('title');`

```js
var createImage = function(src, title) {
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = src;
 img.title = title;
 return img;
};

var imgArray = [];
imgArray.push(createImage('Assets/banana.png', 'banana'));
divOne.append(imgArray[0]);
var a = $('img', "#divOne").attr('title');
console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divOne" class="div"></div>
```

Comment: This answer requires jQuery, but jQuery is not needed to solve this.